# Was a copy of my variable created here?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that will run every time I open up cmd prompt in Windows with some nice aliases. Sometimes when I'm working I have to keep referring to one specific directory and then move around and come back to it; So far so good but I can't figure out this problem I'm getting with a variable.

```
::initialize variable to root
set cwd=C:\                
::save current directory
doskey setcwd=set cwd=%CD% 
::jump back to saved directory 
doskey gocwd=cd %cwd%      
::print the variable 
doskey pcwd=echo %cwd%
```

Here is what goes on when I try to use these commands:

```
(opening up cmd.exe, it starts in C:\Users\<my user name>, batch file executes)

> pwd
C:\
> cd foo\bar\baz
foo\bar\baz
> pwd 
foo\bar\baz
> pcwd
C:\                     <-- expected, havent set it yet 
> echo %cwd%            <-- checking it manually just to make sure it says 'C:\' 
(no output)             <-- strange, I thought I set it to C:\ 
> setcwd 
> pcwd
C:\                     <-- what? I thought I set it to the current directory
> echo %cwd%            <-- checking again to make sure
C:\Users\<my user name> <-- what- I don't even... 
> gocwd
> pwd
C:\                     <-- how...
```

So that's essentially the problem I'm facing; it looks like I somehow have two different instances of the `cwd` variable; the one in my batch file, and the one I'm manually printing out?

*Note I did include `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top of my file, understanding that the variables I use in the definition of my doskeys won't be expanded until I execute the commands, and not at the time the file is read; still didn't help.

Comment: I never said it was; I'm working with a batch file; I'm trying to do something like I did in bash but on windows; what part of that was difficult for you to understand? Rather than getting rude and down-voting my question which you obviously haven't even fully read (or you would have understood I in no way even once claimed batch was bash) why don't you try to actually help me and answer the question?

Comment: That attitude is sure to get you tons of help :)

Comment: P.s i haven't downvoted anything ever, check my profile :)

Comment: Well then I'd prefer if whoever was down-voting, if they could please tell me what about my question isn't up to par so that I could improve on my questions in the future - i'm asking about something I truly don't understand and trying to give as much info as I can about my situation - I thought that was how stackoverflow questions were supposed to be?

Comment: There appears to be a sad contingent of Overflowers who mechanically downvote any question that isn't to their exacting standards. Some even if they are of the opinion that everyone should convert to Powershell. Others simply because they assume that batch=bash with no differing opinios allowed. It's easy for such people to forget that they were once beginners too.

Comment: @Magoo the bash part is irrelevant though(enough to be tagged anyway) and it showing up under the bash tag wastes peoples time reading something that is entirely to do with programming a batch script.

Comment: @Magoo Yeah it's frustrating
JID: Well that makes perfect sense to me - I can definitely see how my including the bash script was irrelevant; thanks for the info I'll take it out.

Comment: @Grandclosing: I suggest you to review `pushd` and `popd` commands...

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide us with the entire batch. If you have a `setlocal` command in that batch, then any variations to the environment will be backed out when the batch terminates.

```
::initialize variable to root
cwd=C:\
```

is incorrect. You need

```
::initialize variable to root
SET cwd=C:\
```

With the invisible `setlocal`, `cwd` would remain "empty"

Comment: Sorry; `cwd=C:\ ` was a typo on my part; I did use `set`

Comment: Best to cut-and-paste your original code into your question, then censor-out any sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
::initialize variable to root
set "cwd=C:\."
::save current directory
doskey setcwd=set "cwd=%%CD%%"
::jump back to saved directory 
doskey gocwd=if defined cwd (cd /d "%%cwd%%") else echo NO CWD
::print the variable 
doskey pcwd=if defined cwd (echo %%cwd%%) else echo NO CWD
```

If you don't escape the variables when you define the macro, there will be no reference to the variable inside the macro, as the parser replaces variables with their values at parse time.